# reading progress database(.db file)

Tags: database, progress-db

I have old Progress database. and I want to read an old Progress .db file. 
How can I do it?
Progress version year is 1994. 16 bit. 
It was running Novell netware but now it is finish.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Progress executables that go with whatever release of Progress you have that is also on a compatible platform (DOS or Novell would work).  I believe that the last Novell release was Progress version 6.  (The current release of Progress is OpenEdge 11.)

If you have the executables still on a PC associated with that system then you should be able to access the db.  However, if the database is associated with an application and the application was distributed without source code you probably only have a runtime license.  Which probably means that you cannot easily extract the data.

If you have access to more recent copies of Progress you could also try converting and updating the db to something more up to date.  But that will also be non-trivial as there have been significant architectural changes in the last 25 years.

The files are binary and the format is proprietary.  You cannot just read them in an editor.  That software also pre-dates things like ODBC by a decade or so -- so you won't find any relief that way either.

Your best bet is probably to find a consultant who has a fully capable copy of v6 who is willing to do the work.

Comment: thank for useful comment. I found my important informations in database table .d file. how can I read it with the tables. when I open it with PIEW it has 38000 line but I want to read it in the tables. is it possible.

Comment: The files are binary and the format is proprietary.